# ASP.NET core 6 with angular

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there any option in asp.net core 6 with angular directly use proxy server instead of every time build angular.
Previously i use spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/"); in startup.cs file

Comment: You can try add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions) nuget.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.